# How to remove encoding 'b' in a string which was read from file?

Tags: python, character-encoding, google-colaboratory

```
trainLabels = files.upload()
labels = (trainLabels['LabelsTrain.txt']).splitlines()
trainLabels = [k.encode("utf-8") for k in labels]
```

I am using Google Colab to train a network. I read in image labels from a text file and they seem to be encoded.

The labels show up as:

```
[b'53.239448782705836', b'24.01860123103387', b'32.0400103628653']
```

So I am trying to remove the `'b'` by using `encode("utf-8")`.
 However, I get the following error:

```
  AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

How would I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read file, the strings are still has byte type encoded in `utf` or `ascii`.

In the python, `encode` makes string to `byte type`, and your data is already `b`(byte type).

So its impossible that `byte` encode to `Unicode byte` again in python. It makes that error.

It looks like readable in python interpreter(it just display for readable to human), but **real data is encoded in Unicode byte format.**

So, Using `decode` makes bytestrem into Unicode text in python interpreter, it makes handle text without `b`

So, it'll be works well with changing `encode` to `decode`.

```
trainLabels = [k.decode("utf-8") for k in labels]
```